# How to correct this code error in PHP - Trying to access array offset on value of type null?

Tags: php, php-curl

I am following a blog ([blog](https://webkul.com/blog/calculate-distance-two-zip-codes/#:%7E:text=This%20is%20very%20simple%20to%20calculate%20the%20distance%20through%20google%20API.&text=you%20have%20to%20call%20an,of%20both%20the%20zip%20codes.&text=So%20the%20Distance%20is%209%20km%20.)) to find out latitude-longitude to find out the distance between two pin codes. The code is  as follows

```
<?php
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='201301'&sensor=false";
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$json = curl_exec($curl);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);

$result1[]=$decode['results'][0];
$result2[]=$result1[0]['geometry'];
$result3[]=$result2[0]['location'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result3[0]);
die();
?>
```

The eroor in following lines

```
$result1[]=$decode['results'][0];
$result2[]=$result1[0]['geometry'];
$result3[]=$result2[0]['location'];
```

error is

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Tell me - have you actually used an API key in your request?

Comment: NO in that link we get latitude and longitude and without API KEY. I have seen one from turorial with API key and passing pin code directly to api call. I dont have any API key.

Comment: You'll need one (an API key, that is) - if you `var_dump($decode)`, you'll see an error message stating: "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account".

Comment: Also, you'll need to issue your request as https, not http, cf. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/faq#why_do_i_keep_receiving_status_request_denied

Comment: Have you actually tried pasting that url into the browser directly? [Click here to test](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=201301) ~ which should reveal `"You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs"`

Comment: The Blog post that you are using is dated November 2016. According [to this article](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases) from Google - `"As of September 16, 2019, we began to enforce API key restrictions for API keys used to call the Places Library in the Maps JavaScript API. If you have applied API restrictions to the API keys used with Places Library, Maps JavaScript API and have not selected both Places API and Maps JavaScript API in your API restrictions list, you will begin to receive errors."`

Comment: Ok thank you @Professor Abronsius